# Logged in member can't view order in Store

Tags: expresso-store, ee4, ee4-upgrade

I'm at the tail end of an EE upgrade (to v4) which includes the Store add-on (which per the changelog is EE4 compatible).

In testing, everything seems to be working fine EXCEPT that a logged in user can't view their orders. The area of the page where the code is supposed to render is blank.

Template code looks like this: https://d.pr/n/H607xq

Not sure what to try - docs are thin.

Comment: I'd first try setting $debug to 1 in your index.php file. If you do that, do you see any errors on the page?

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't give any clues. No errors shown. :/

Comment: When you turn on template debugging, do you see your `exp:store:orders` tag? Just a double check that it's actually being called. And the layout is using `{layout:page_content}` somewhere?

Comment: With template debugging on, don't see the tag. And yep, using {layout:page_content}. Going to have to get in touch with Store support I think.